# Amazon Lex & Dialogflow suggestion text as quick buttons for conversation

Tags: actions-on-google, amazon-lex

Just like Suggestion( Quick button ) like in [Actions on Google](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/responses#suggestion_chips), do we also have any class/Function to use in Amazon Lex ?

Actions on Google : `agent.add(new Suggestion(' Your text here ')); // to provide quick suggestion to the user.`

Answer (score 2):

Like Google amazon lex also have a quick suggestion,i.e response cards. Below one is the sample image and JSON object you will get from lex with response cards.[image]

Sample JSON Object from aws-lex which will generate response cards. i.e quick suggestions
for slots.

```
{
  "sampleUtterances": [

  ],
  "slotType": "",
  "slotTypeVersion": "4",
  "slotConstraint": "Optional",
  "valueElicitationPrompt": {
    "messages": [
      {
        "contentType": "PlainText",
        "content": "what do you want to schedule"
      }
    ],
    "responseCard": "{\"version\":1,\"contentType\":\"application/vnd.amazonaws.card.generic\",\"genericAttachments\":[{\"buttons\":[{\"text\":\"sales\",\"value\":\"sales consultation\"}]}]}",
    "maxAttempts": 2
  },
  "priority": 11,
  "name": "appointment"
}
```